# SQL not returning a value whe it is NULL

Tags: sql

I am doing a query, but not all the User_names are displayed only the ones with values. Please check my code and see where I am going wrong

```
Select a.Owner_Id,
     a.Creator_Id,
     b.Name as KPI,
     B.Record_Type,
     B.Resource_Id,
     C.Display_Name,
     Count(a.owner_id) AS MAX,
     case when a.owner_Id is null then c.Display_name else 0 end
from amgr_appointments_tbl A
     left join AMGR_Resources B on A.Owner_Id = b.Resource_Id 
     left join ADMN_User_Details AS C ON A.Creator_Id = C.User_Id   
where b.Resource_Id in('ROE534B758E', 'R0E42A431B5', 'R0E42A4BB3F','R0E42A3E514','R0E42A44D19', 'R0E42A37FBB')
    and b.Record_Type = 3
    and  a.Creator_Id In('AMCKENZIE','ASARAK','CWEIMANN', 'EWOOLDRIDGE', 'GHAVENGA', 'JSTAPELBERG','WILLEMB', 'YRHODA', 'JMALAN')
    and A.App_Date BETWEEN '20160201' and '20160331'
Group by a.Owner_Id, a.Creator_Id, b.Name, B.Record_Type, B.Resource_Id, c.Display_Name
```

Comment: Sorry messed up the question a bit

Comment: Your query starts off with `amgr_appointments_tbl`. To this tbl you join two other tables as `LEFT JOIN`. This will show appointments with no users, but not users with no appointments... If you want to see all users, start from there, or try a `RIGHT JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions on `b` in the `where` clause turn the `left join` to an inner join.  You need to move those conditions to the `on` clause:

```
select . . .
from amgr_appointments_tbl A left join
     AMGR_Resources B
     on A.Owner_Id = b.Resource_Id and
        b.Resource_Id in ('ROE534B758E', 'R0E42A431B5', 'R0E42A4BB3F','R0E42A3E514','R0E42A44D19', 'R0E42A37FBB') and
        b.Record_Type = 3 left join
     ADMN_User_Details C
     on A.Creator_Id = C.User_Id   
where . . .
```

The conditions on the *first* table do belong in the `where` clause.

Comment: The new Query returns everything, all I want it to return are the user specified in the Creater_Id

Comment: The conditions on the `a` table should go in the `where` clause, not the `on` clause.

Comment: still doesn't show the users that don't have values. I know you cant expect sql to bring values when there aren't matching values but there must be a way to retrieve these values by putting in a null or a 0 when the user hasn't returned any values?

Comment: @Stix . . . Perhaps you should ask another question with sample data and desired results.